# Using spread properties versus the whole object when passing data to a component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

To pass data into a Svelte component, you can use spread properties, like

```
<MyComponent {...dataObject} />
```

However, you can also pass the data object itself

```
<MyComponent {dataObject} />
```

For me it is not clear what the advantage is of using the first construct (so, why it exists). Is not passing the object itself always more clear and faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, passing the object is more explicit and easier for the compiler to optimize, so it should be the preferred approach in most cases IMO.

I believe the spread syntax should be used only when it gives a clear and important benefit, that is when it's obvious that it's better and you wouldn't ask such a question ;)

Such situations usually arise when a component is a sort of thin wrapper around another one, where the spread would be used in conjunction with the special `$$props` or `$$restProps` variables

```html
<script>
  export let child
</script>

<main>
  <svelte:component this={child} {...$$restProps} />
</main>

<style>
  main {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
```

Also, when you compute a lot of props to be passed to a component, the spread syntax can help make your markup more readable. And if you pass those same props to multiple children, it can help dry your code.

```html
<script>
  import { foo, bar, baz, bat, man, ... } from './util.js'

  export let input

  $: props = {
    foo: foo(input),
    bar: bar(input),
    baz: baz(input),
    bat: bat(input),
    man: man(input),
    ...
  }
</script>

<Child {...props} id="1" />

<Child {...props} id="2" />
```